# ZK - Combobox Selected Item Image

Tags: image, combobox, icons, zk

Anyone know a way to display an image/icon with the selected item in a ZK `Combobox`. For example, this [ZK Live Demo](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/combobox/simple_combobox) shows how to put images on each `Comboitem` in the dropdown. However, selecting an item in this example, the combobox displays the label of that item.. but not the image.

Comment: The selected item is in a `<input type=text>` HTML tag and I think you can't add an image to it. I think if you like to do so, you have to manipulate the zk component. Maybe a good feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you need to customize it (copy image node of selected item to combobox) your self, simple sample:

```
<zk xmlns:w="client">
    <style>
        .z-combobox-inp,
        .z-combobox-rounded-inp {
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <combobox>
        <attribute w:name="bind_"><![CDATA[
            function (a, b, c) {
                this.$bind_(a, b, c);
                // anchor used to position selected image
                var n = this.$n(),
                    ref = n.firstChild,
                    span = document.createElement('span');
                jq(span).css('position', 'relative')
                    .addClass('custom-selected-image-anchor');
                n.insertBefore(span, ref);
            }
        ]]></attribute>
        <attribute w:name="_hilite2"><![CDATA[
            function (sel, opts) {
                this.$_hilite2(sel, opts);
                if (opts && opts.sendOnSelect && sel) {
                    var $anchor = jq(this.$n()).find('.custom-selected-image-anchor');
                    $anchor.find('.custom-selected-image')
                        .each(function () {
                            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
                        });
                    $anchor[0].appendChild(
                        jq(sel.getImageNode()).clone() // clone node
                            .css({'position': 'absolute', // add style
                                'left': '0px',
                                'top': '3px'}) // also add class
                            .addClass('custom-selected-image')[0]       
                    );
                }
            }
        ]]></attribute>
        <comboitem label="test" image="images/battery.gif" />
        <comboitem label="test 2" image="images/left_arrow.png" />
    </combobox>
</zk>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible... They would certainly have some reference to that in the documentation, how to get image on a combobox selected item value or something ... But did you try the forum? They would help you for sure!